# Lua: set every new element in table to a default value

Tags: hash, lua, lua-table

I want to get the most frequent k-sized substring in a string. To achieve this, I'm using a table to store the number of occurrences for each substring. Here's the code:

```
function frequentWords(seq, k)
  local subs = ""
  local counter = {}
  for i = 1,(seq:len()-k+1) do
    subs = seq:sub(i, i+k-1)
    counter[subs] = (counter[subs] and counter[subs] + 1 or 1)
    --print(subs .. ": " .. counter[subs])
  end
end
```

The line `counter[subs] = (counter[subs] and counter[subs] + 1 or 1)` has the same mean of  `counter[subs] = (counter[subs] ? counter[subs]+1 : 1)`. This line would be only `counter[subs] = counter[subs] + 1` if we could set every new `counter` element with `0`. Is this possible in Lua? If not, what's the best way of doing something similar?

For instance, in Ruby, this is done by declaring a Hash like this:

```
counter = Hash.new(0)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set an `__index` metamethod in `counter` to return 0:

```
setmetatable(counter,{__index=function () return 0 end})
```

but this is easier and clearer:

```
counter[subs] = (counter[subs] or 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, lhf's solution is sufficient. Just for completeness, I would like to mention there is a more complex way, that enables some slightly more complex functionality. Specifically, it acts "as you would expect" when you use it with mutable values, such as table: it both creates the item, and assigns it to the key when created.

```
function defaultTable(constructor)
  local new = {}
  local function initIndex(key)
    local value = constructor()
    new[key] = value
    return value
  end
  setmetatable(new, {__index=initIndex})
  return new
end
```

Comment: You probably need `rawset` to avoid loops.

Comment: I am only using __index, which only is called if you are trying to get a value, and only if there is no item at that key in the table. I don't override the writing part, it works as normal.